# How to auto focus in Batch Files

Tags: batch-file

I'm using this batch file to auto log in

```
@echo off
set "username=username"
set "password=password"
start "" "https://auth.voxmedia.com/login?community_id=372&return_to=https://www.theverge.com/"
"%username%{tab}%password%{enter}"
```

however to work this needs to auto focus on the username textbox what command would I use this is a proof of concept and the text box I mean is the textbox on the login prompt where one would write in their username currently it just brings me to the logon page of the example site the verge

Answer (score 0):

There is no way how pure batch could ever interact with GUI. There is also no such thing as `{tab}` or `{enter}` in batch. If you want to interact with GUI elements or simulate keystrokes you will have to use a more powerful script language. I prefer AutoIT but I guess VBScript will work as well.